# How to check if Date column is null in workflow sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

In Infopath I have a Date Column which i need to check in workflow like if date column is empty i have to stop the workflow. How to achieve this?

I tried using setting variable and parameters but none works.

ScreenShot:
[image]

Comment: Could you please share screenshot of workflow actions where you have set variables and ended workflow?

Comment: Screen Shot Attached

Answer (score 3):

Can you try following. I have just tried it. It may meet your requirement.

1. Create a calculated column named `IsEmptyDate` or anything you like which outputs text.

Paste the following formula.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(StartDate),"Y","N")
```

After applying this formula, my list looks like following and that helps me to believe it should work.

[image]

2. Now in the workflow check if `IsEmptyDate` equals `Y`, then stop the
   workflow.

Comment: Sure I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

1) Create another list column of type Date and Time called EmptyDate, using the default settings, except deselect Add to default view.

2) Use this field to compare to your date field in the workflow condition, using equals or not equals:
[image]

3) Hide EmptyDate from users by not adding it to any views. Also, hide it from the view/edit form by following these steps:

4) Go to List settings -> Advanced settings and ensure Allow management of content types is set to yes.

5) Go back to the List settings page and click on Item in the Content Types section of the page.

6) Click on EmptyDate in the Columns section of the page.

7) Select Hidden (Will not appear in forms).

https://howardmcd.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/how-to-check-if-a-date-field-is-blank-in-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/